# Memory allocation for a variant-typed token

Tags: c++, performance

I am making an interpreter for a custom programming language (concatenative, soft-typed) and for that purpose I have a central datatype `Token`. A Token can be of one of the many different types, either of scalar ones or vector ones. To minimize the amount of memory, I used a `union` first but then I could only use plain-old data structures in the union, so I resorted to a `struct` with all the fields (`long asInteger;`, `boost::shared_ptr<std::string> asString`, ...). That was of course a bad idea from a memory consumption viewpoint but it got the job done.

The project has grown quite a bit since the original formulation and is now nearing 5000 lines altogether (mainly consisting of various functions that are built in the interpreter). Since the `Token` datatype was almost 100 bytes long (making an array of  1,000,000 integers almost 100 megabytes for example), the original formulation showed massively inadequate. Today I revamped the implementation to dynamically allocate the memory needed for each element with copy semantics so that I got something similar to the `union` if I could use it with classes.

This is the new class definition:

```
typedef struct _st_VariableData {
  char name[32];
  Context *context;
  vector<long> index;
} VariableData;

typedef struct _st_FuncCallData {
  char asFunctionName[32];
} FuncCallData;

// Opaque pointer type
typedef struct _st_HandleData {
  void * ptr;
  long size;
} HandleData;

class Token {
protected:
    TokenType tokenType_;

    template<class T>
    inline void copyToken(void * src, void * dst)
    {
      *static_cast<T*>(dst) = 
          *static_cast<T*>(src);
    };

    template<class T>
    inline void deleteValue()
    {
      delete static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    void deleteData()
    {
        switch (tokenType_)
        {
            case T_OPERATOR:  deleteValue<OperatorType>(); break; 
            case T_FUNCCALL:  deleteValue<FuncCallData>(); break; 
            case T_VARIABLE:  deleteValue<VariableData>(); break; 
            case T_INTEGER:   deleteValue<long>(); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      deleteValue<bool>(); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     deleteValue<double>(); break;
            case T_STRING:    deleteValue<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(); break; 
            case T_CODEBLOCK:  
            case T_ARRAY:     deleteValue<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    deleteValue<HandleData>(); break;
            default: ;
        }
    }

    void allocate(const TokenType tokenType)
    {       
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case T_OPERATOR:  data = new OperatorType; break; 
            case T_FUNCCALL:  data = new FuncCallData; break; 
            case T_VARIABLE:  data = new VariableData; break; 
            case T_INTEGER:   data = new long; break; 
            case T_BOOL:      data = new bool;  break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     data = new double; break;
            case T_STRING:    data = new boost::shared_ptr<std::string>; break; 
            case T_CODEBLOCK:  
            case T_ARRAY:     data = new boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>; break;
            case T_HANDLE:    data = new HandleData; break;
            default: data = NULL;
        }     
    };

    void * data;

public:
    char * fileName;
    int lineNum;

    const TokenType type()
    {       
        return tokenType_;
    };

    const TokenType type() const
    {       
        return tokenType_;
    };

    void set_type(const TokenType tokenType)
    {
        deleteData();
        tokenType_ = tokenType;
        allocate(tokenType);
    };

    Token() : tokenType_ (T_EMPTY) { data = NULL; }; 

    Token(const TokenType tokenType) : tokenType_ (tokenType)  
    {
        allocate(tokenType);
    };

    Token(const Token& old_token)  
    {
        fileName = old_token.fileName;
        lineNum  = old_token.lineNum;
        tokenType_ = old_token.tokenType_;
        allocate(old_token.tokenType_);
        switch (old_token.tokenType_)
        {
            case T_OPERATOR:  copyToken<OperatorType>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_FUNCCALL:  copyToken<FuncCallData>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_VARIABLE:  copyToken<VariableData>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_INTEGER:   copyToken<long>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      copyToken<bool>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     copyToken<double>(old_token.data, data); break;
            case T_STRING:    copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(old_token.data, data); break; 
            case T_CODEBLOCK:  
            case T_ARRAY:     copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(old_token.data, data); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    copyToken<HandleData>(old_token.data, data); break;
            default: ;
        }       
    };

    template<class T>
    T& retreive()
    {
        return *static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    template<class T>
    const T& retreive() const
    {
        return *static_cast<T*>(data);
    };

    void operator=(const Token &rhs) 
    {
        fileName = rhs.fileName;
        lineNum  = rhs.lineNum;
        set_type(rhs.tokenType_);
        switch (rhs.tokenType_)
        {
            case T_OPERATOR:  copyToken<OperatorType>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_FUNCCALL:  copyToken<FuncCallData>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_VARIABLE:  copyToken<VariableData>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_INTEGER:   copyToken<long>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_BOOL:      copyToken<bool>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_FLOAT:     copyToken<double>(rhs.data, data); break;
            case T_STRING:    copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::string>>(rhs.data, data); break; 
            case T_CODEBLOCK:  
            case T_ARRAY:     copyToken<boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<Token>>>(rhs.data, data); break;
            case T_HANDLE:    copyToken<HandleData>(rhs.data, data); break;
            default: ;
        }       
    };

    ~Token()
    {
       deleteData();
    };
};
```

Now the above code **works**, but is terribly slow (200% slower than the previous implementation). A profiler shows that almost half of the execution time is spent on `new` and `free()`. I have tried using placement new syntax with a `char data[50]` and that speeds it up a lot but still not as fast as original (about 20% slower).

I am quite new to C++ (this is my first large project) so please excuse me if I have made some blatant mistakes arising from misconceptions. Generally I would like to minimize the memory allocation cost while also minimizing the required memory.

If this is usually done a whole different way, please advise me how to do it. The entire 
source code (bleeding-edge without build automation) is available [here](http://www.ojdip.net/stutsk/stutsk-current/stutsk-current.tar.gz).

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is solved very elegantly by [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Not only is it easier and more efficient, it’s also completely type safe (meaning, you cannot accidentally retrieve a wrong type) when using the `boost::apply_visitor` template function to access data.

Furthermore, I’d separate an object and its token representation. Objects can be the result of a computation (1 + 1, say) but this has no representation in the source file, right? This way, you can save storing he line number for tokens which aren’t in a file. I’d also refrain from storing the filename for each token – wouldn’t it be enough to store that once?

With that in mind, a token can be represented by the following variant:

```
struct token_array;

typedef boost::variant<
    OperatorType,
    FuncCallData,
    VariableData,
    long,
    …,
    boost::recursive_wrapper<token_array>
> token;

struct token_array {
    std::vector<token> tokens;
};
```

Note that you no longer need to take care of (de)allocation and copying yourself.

---

Apart from that, your code features a few peculiarities from C:

```
typedef struct _st_FuncCallData {
  char asFunctionName[32];
} FuncCallData;
```

First of all, there is no need to do `typedef struct … { } …;` in C++. Second of all, the struct name is invalid: in the global namespace, names starting with an underscore are reserved to the implementation in C++.

The following is completely equivalent:

```
struct FuncCallData {
    char asFunctionName[32];
};
```

I’d also question the usefulness of using a fixed-size char array here instead of just a `std::string` but oh well.

Comment: Thank you! I've since tried with Boost Variant, but the code ended up being slower than before, the profiler showed that a very large amount of time was spent in some `boost::variant` function. I did not use `boost::recursive_wrapper`, so maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: @Tibor Which function was the time spent in? Anyway, if Boost.Variant turns out to be too slow I would nonetheless look at its implementation for inspiration. Having the multiple `switch`es that you have is a definite no-go.

Comment: That would be the um... boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl<boost::mpl::int_<0>,boost::detail::variant::visitation_impl_step<boost::mpl::l_iter<boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<9>,enum _en_OperatorType,boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<8>,_st_FuncCallData,boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<7>,_st_VariableData,boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<6>,boost::shared_ptr<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >